# Is it OK to use unknown HTML tags?

Tags: html

Correct me if I'm mistaken, but AFAIK, unknown HTML tags in markup (i.e. tags not defined in the HTML spec, like say, `<foobar>`) will eventually be treated as a regular `<div>` in an HTML 5 browser environment.

I'm thinking: how supportable is this practice? I mean, if I use unknown HTML tags in my markup, what pitfalls can I expect? Will [a velociraptor pounce on me within the next few seconds](http://xkcd.com/292/)?

The reason I ask is that if these tags defer to `<div>`, I can potentially use these tags in a more semantic manner than, say, assigning class names that identify modules. [Have a look at this article, for example, of a `.media` class](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/). Now what if instead of writing up that CSS to target `.media`, I make it target `<media>` instead? In my opinion, that makes the markup much more readable and maintainable, but I do acknowledge that it's not "correct" HTML.

#### EDIT

Just to be transparent, I *did* find [this SO question from a few years back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags). It's been closed as off-topic, but I feel that I have a valid point in my own wording. It's a close duplicate, I admit, but it's from a few years back, so there might have been changes in the general environ of opinions across web developers about the topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should always approach HTML as it is defined in its respective specification. "Defining" new tags is a bit of an extreme approach. It might pass a browser check because it implements various failsafes, but there is no guarantee of this. You're entering the land of Undefined Behaviour, at best. Not to mention you will fail validation tests, but you seem to be aware of that.

If you wish to be more semantically expressive in your markup, you can use HTML5 which defines quite a bit of more descriptive tags for describing the structure of your page instead of generic `div`s which need to be appended `id`s or `class`es.

In the end, a short answer: No, it's bad practice, you shouldn't do it and there could be unforeseen problems later on in your development.

Comment: What about Web Components?

Comment: There could always be unforseen problems later on in development.  <future>The future is by its nature unknown.</future>

Comment: See here for the long answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27869027/258482

Answer (score 109):

user1309389 had a very good answer, and I agree with the appeal to the spec. But I disagree with their conclusion, and I think they're wrong about made-up elements leading to "undefined behaviour". I want to propose an alternative way of thinking about it, rooted in how the spec and browsers *actually* handle made-up elements.

It's 2015, we're on the verge of the [CustomElement](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) spec being widely adopted, and polyfills are readily available. Now is a great time to be wondering about "making up your own elements". In the near future, you'll be able to create new elements with your own choice of tag and behaviour in a fully standard and supported way that everyone can love. But until this lands in all browsers, and until the majority of people are using supporting browsers, you can take advantage of the hard work of the [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org) or [X-Tags](http://www.x-tags.org) projects to check out the future of custom elements in a nearly-standard and mostly-supported way that quite a few people can love. This is probably the "right thing" to do. But it doesn't answer your question, and frankly I find "just use X" or "don't do X" to be less helpful than "here's how the spec covers this, and here's what browsers do". So, here's what I love.

Against the heartfelt recommendation (and sometimes screaming) of much of the web dev community, I've been working with "made-up" elements for the past year, in all of my production projects, without a polyfill, and I've had no unsolvable issues (yet), and no complaints. How? By relying on the standard behaviour of [HTMLUnknownElement](http://ryanmorr.com/determine-html5-element-support-in-javascript/), the part of the W3C spec that covers the case of "made-up" elements. If a browser encounters an unrecognized HTML element, there is a *well-defined and unambiguous* way that it should be handled, and HTMLUnknownElement defines that behaviour, and you can build on top of that. HTMLUnknownElement also has to be powerful and *correct* enough to "not break the web" when encountering all the tags that are now obsolete, like the `<blink>` tag. It's not recommended that you use HTMLUnknownElement, but in theory and in practice, there's absolutely no harm in doing so, if you know what you're doing.

So how does HTMLUnknownElement work? It is just an extension of the HTMLElement interface, which is the standard interface underlying all HTML elements. Unlike most other elements however, HTMLUnknownElement doesn't add any special behaviour — you get a raw element, unadorned with any special behaviour nor constraining rules about use. The [HTMLDivElement interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-div-element) works almost exactly the same way, extending HTMLElement and adding almost no additional behaviour. Put simply, making up your own element is *almost* identical to using a div or span.

What I like about "making-up" elements is the change of mindset. You should use **or invent** HTML elements based on several factors, ranging from how clear it makes the markup to read, to how the browser and screen readers and search engines parse your code, to how likely your code is to be "correct" by some objective measure. I sparingly use made-up elements, but I use in exactly the way Richard described, to make things more meaningful for the author of the HTML, not just meaningful to a computer service that extracts metadata. When used in a consistent way across a team, there can be a big benefit since made-up elements can concisely express what they're for.

I particularly like using made-up elements to indicate when I will be using JS to define extra behaviour for an element. For instance, if I have an element that will have children added/removed by JS, I will use a made-up element as a clue that this element is subject to special behaviour. By the same token, I don't use a made-up element when a standard element will suffice. You will see `<dynamic-list>` live happily next to `<div>` in my code.

Now, about those pesky validators. Yes, using made-up elements isn't "valid" in the sense that it won't pass a "validator". But many commonly used features, patterns, and systems of modern HTML and JS development fail all the W3C validators. The validators aren't the law — the spec is. And the law isn't binding — the implementations in all the browsers are. The utility of validators has been dimishing for years as the flexability of HTML has been increasing, and as browsers have shifted in their relationship to the spec. Validators are great for people who aren't comfortable with HTML and need guidance. But if you're comfortable taking your guidance from the spec and from browser implementations, there's no reason to worry about being flunked by the validator. Certainly, if you follow many of the guidelines offered by Google, Apple, Microsoft, etc, for implementing any experimental features, you'll be working outside the bounds of the validator. This is absolutely an okay thing to do, so long as you're doing it deliberately and you know enough about what you're doing.

Therefore, if you're going to make up your own elements and rely on HTMLUnknownElement, don't just treat it like a wild west. You need to follow a few simple rules.

1. You have to use a hyphen in the name of your tag. If you do, you are guaranteed to never collide with a future edition of the HTML spec. So never say `<wrong>`, always say `<quite-right>`.
2. Made-up elements can't be self-closing — you have to close them with a closing tag. You can't just say `<wrong>` or `<still-wrong />`, you have to say `<totally-good></totally-good>`.
3. You have to define a `display` property for your element in CSS, otherwise the rendering behaviour is undefined.

That's about it. If you do these things, you should be good to use made-up elements in IE9 and up, relying on the safety net of the HTMLUnknownElement. For me, the benefits far, far outweigh the costs, so I've been using this pattern heavily. I run a SaaS site catering to major industrial corporations, and I've had no trouble or complaints thus far. If you have to support older versions of IE, it's wise to stay far away from any "2015" technology or their crude approximations, and stay safely within the well-trodden parts of the spec.

So, in summary, the answer to your question is "yes, if you know what you're doing".

Comment: On the cusp of stuff like Polymer, etc, I can definitely see where you're coming from. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: For reference see also what Angular 2 is doing with web components

Comment: Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker (validator) here. I recently added support for custom elements to the checker. The gist of it is that the checker no longer reports errors for element names such as `quite-right` that have hyphens in them. For a few more details, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508533/w3c-validation-for-ui-select/28711028#28711028

Comment: I just started using these on a page I was working on, and thought I should probably check it would actually work on all (or most) browsers. If it works on IE9, though, there is absolutely no reason it wouldn't work for good browsers.

Thanks for the (5-year-old) answer, and for the 'rules' to guide use of these wonderful tools for easier-to-read HTML.

Answer (score 10):

No. You will fail validation, you will get random issues cross browser and you WILL be eaten by said dinosaurs. CSS is the answer if you want your page to behave predictably.

Comment: and, of course, we don't want to get eaten by dinosaurs. in all seriousness, points well taken. :)

Answer (score 10):

**Yes We Can**.

There is a new spec going on about custom elements/tag - http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/.

Only issue with this is you have to use js to register your new element

You can read more about this at

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements

Answer (score 3):

W3C says:

> HTML5 supports unknown tags as inline elements, but it recommends CSS
>   styling for it.

Here is the source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_browsers.asp

Answer (score 2):

Rule #1 of browser interoperability is: don't have errors. No matter how many browsers you test in, there are always browsers you can't test, for instance because they don't exist yet.
Also, unknown elements will be treated as `<span>`, not `<div>` by most browsers currently.

If it's really source readability(*) you're after, you should look into XML+XSLT.
That way, you can use all the tag names you want, and make them behave in any way you like and you don't have to worry that `<media>` will be a real element in some future version of HTML.

One good real world example is the element `<picture>`. If a website ever used `<picture>` and relied on the notion that this element would have no styles or special content by itself, they are in trouble now!

(*) With XML+XSLT, the readability will be in the XML part, not the XSLT part, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Generally not recommendable, e.g. IE wont apply css-styles to unknown tags.

All other browsers render unknown tags as `inline`-Elements (which causes problems with nesting).

I recommend you the following article: http://diveintohtml5.info/ There is a section about unknown tags.

Comment: Now incorrect. CSS works for custom elements in IE11+ in edge mode. Probably works for IE10 to but I didn't try. I believe that for IE8/IE9 you can get it to work by "registering" the tag using document.createElement('my-custom-tag') to register `my-custom-tag` as a valid tag (your custom tags should always contain a dash).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use a lot of them into my Webkit-powered game GUI system, and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are talking about `<media>`, it's could be great but if html6 adds this tag for another element, your code won't be retrocompatible.

Comment: The rule for custom elements is that you need to use a hyphen in the name. If you do that, you're guaranteed to not clash with future versions of the spec. So <media-item> would be fine, now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The one downside that worries me is what if a custom tag I use now, becomes an official HTML-tag next year or even later?

Therefore how about this: Instead of custom tags use 'div' + a custom CSS-class.

CSS-classes are meant to be custom, it is definitely ok to have your own custom CSS-classes. Your div can then further have any number of CSS-classes associated with it making the semantic machinery even more flexible, you could call it multiple inheritance.

Instead of div you could use span for the same purpose. I would like to use something shorter actually, say p but unfortunately p has its own special behavior of what happens if you don't close it.

But definitely if you go the route of expressing semantics with CSS-classes then it does help to use a tag-name that is as short as possible. I wish there was something shorter than div, say for instance t for 'tag'.

Answer (score 0):

By default, custom elements main parts of many JavaScript-Framwork. It is state of the art in modern javascript.:

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

*Is it OK to use unknown HTML tags?* If you ask wrong questions, you get allways wrong answers. If you define your unknown tag with javascript as a CustomeElement , your unknown tag is no longer part of the HTML5/HTML-definition.

Yes, you can use unknown tags, if you define the tag in your javascript.

Answer (score -2):

What's wrong with the judicious use of  < !-- *your stuff here* -- >. It worked for scripts back around the time of the Cretaceous–Paleogene boundary. Dinosaurs ceased to be a problem around that time, that is apart from the flying, feathered variety.

Answer (score -3):

It's bad practice and you should not do it. The browser renders it as div as fallback solution in most cases but it's not valid html and therefore never will pass a validity test.

Comment: who's validity test?