# Why browsers parses custom tags in HTML5?

Tags: html, tags, semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to use unknown HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830682/is-it-ok-to-use-unknown-html-tags)

I've tested a custom tag `<oles-tag> ... </oles-tag>` in Chrome and IE9.

I use HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

HTML5 does NOT support custom tags. The code won't validate, but the browsers parses it anyway. I can even target it with CSS...

Why does browsers parse custom tags when it's not standardized valid code?

And why shouldn't I just use custom tags for the sake of semantic code?

Comment: An intering discussion on the subject can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags

Comment: Doesn't the standard mandate parsing unrecognized tags?

Comment: @Adam: The last line is a duplicate of that question, but the rest is asking something entirely different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does browsers parse custom tags, when it's not standardized and valid code?

To make it forward-compatible. Just imagine if it was impossible for you to style `<article>` elements in old browsers because `<article>` didn't exist when those old browsers were written. That'd be terrible, wouldn't it? *glares at IE*

> And why shouldn't I just use custom tags for the sake of semantic code?

Because no one else (programs) recognizes those tags, therefore they're not semantic. The reason why elements like `<article>` are considered semantic is because they have an *established* use. When you use a custom element that doesn't have an established use, it could be interpreted in a number of ways, leading to inconsistency among programs. *glares at `<b>` and `<i>`*

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to be lenient with the markup. This is partly historically rooted in difficulties to adopt the complex SGML syntax.

There has been a movement toward strictness in the late 90s, resulting in creation of [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), where every mistake results in a catastrophic failure. If you prefer strictness, there seems to be a version of [XHTML adapted for HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#XHTML5).

XHTML has another interesting feature - you can define and use custom tags all you want, in fact this was [one of the two major reasons](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#why) for it's development.

Comment: Good thing SGML is no more in HTML5.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, they finally got rid of it and kept being lenient. A good thing IMHO