# Angular custom directives are failing in w3 validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, w3c-validation

When I use custom directives of angular, the html page fails in w3 validation. Help me to overcome this issue.

Eg:

```
<div>
    <share-news news-title="{{...}}" news-content="{{...}}"></share-news>
</div>
```

When I use the above code,

I am getting the error like 
Element share-news not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: Could you add the template of the directive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [W3C validation for <ui-select>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508533/w3c-validation-for-ui-select)

Answer (score 0):

While the initial source of the page body (before angular processes an ng-app element) may not adhere to the W3C standards, if you use "replace: true" in directives, custom elements are replaced by a template HTML, which can be valid. So, in this case, you can think about an angular element as just a placeholder that is replaced with the terminal HTML output.