# How to validate HTML utilizing Web Components

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, w3c-validation

The title pretty much speaks for itself.

Is there any possible way to make [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org) validate HTML pages using [Web Components](http://webcomponents.org) and more specifically [Google Polymer](http://polymer-project.org)?

I've read recently an old interview with one of the creators of the *Nu Checker* who said that, for now, he has no intention to worry about web components as they are not yet widely supported. I don't correctly remember the date of the interview, but there are plenty of polyfills that will make web components work just fine in anything IE11+.

*Once web components become more widely supported*, he said, then they'll have to figure something out..

I've recently finished developing a project I've submitted for review on [ThemeForest](http://themeforest.net?ref=TonyBogdanov) and the only reason it got soft rejected (disabled) was that it wasn't valid HTML.

Now I'm quite confused and don't really know what to do. The whole project works just fine in any browser I've tested above IE11, but the validator won't even get past my very first `<tb-main>` element as it's not part of the valid list of `<body>` flow elements.

What would be your suggestion on the matter?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508533/w3c-validation-for-ui-select/28711028#28711028 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607437/should-i-care-about-w3c-validation/29023301#29023301

Comment: @sideshowbarker So, the answer is essentially *No* – no way to validate it.