# Tbody strange behavior with javascript selection

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In code snippet bellow we have 0 element by class name **abc**:

```js
var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
console.log('tbody: ' + tbody.length)

var unKnown = document.getElementsByClassName('edf');
console.log('unKnown: ' + unKnown.length)
```

```html
   <tbody class="abc">
      <tr><td>Hi!</td></tr>
   </tbody>
   
   <dflgkjldk class="edf" />
```

But the unknown element has found by javasctip. Do you know the reason?

Comment: `<tbody>` is completely ignored because it is not valid outside of `<table>` I guess. If you inspect the document, you can see that it is not there. Are you asking why incorrectly placed tags/elements are ignored, but unknown elements are not?

Comment: If you `inspect` the area, you have `<dflgkjldk class"edf">` tag, but there is no tbody tag.

Comment: @Felix Kling,  Yes: *why incorrectly placed tags/elements are ignored, but unknown elements are not* .

Comment: But why it is visible? And i was thinking js only works by text and does not matter what text. Isn't it?

Comment: *"And i was thinking js only works by text and does not matter what text."* The DOM APIs work on the DOM generated from the HTML, not on the HTML itself. The DOM generated by the browser does not contain the `tbody` node, hence JS cannot find it. This is not a JavaScript but an HTML/DOM question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think that if you use incorrect element (read know element incorrectly your example of tbody) the browser is smart enough to filter it out from the DOM.

Unknown element is included because in HTML you can specify your own elements. And browser don't know how to handle them by default but it knows it should include it in the DOM.

Read this about unknow element and why are they useful: [Is it OK to use unknown HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830682/is-it-ok-to-use-unknown-html-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Missing the "Table" element renders the known "tbody" tag incorrect and therefor it is ignored. If you just wrap your tbody with a "table" tag, it works.

```js
var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
console.log('tbody: ' + tbody.length)

var unKnown = document.getElementsByClassName('edf');
console.log('unKnown: ' + unKnown.length)
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody class="abc">
      <tr><td>Hi!</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
   
   <dflgkjldk class="edf" />
```