# HTML align items and font color

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.div1  {
    align-items: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1">
    <img src="smiley.gif">
    One<br>Two<br>Three<br><font color="red">Four</font>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the above code to display an image and the text `One, Two, Three, Four` next to it. I am trying to make `Four` have a red color but it places it seperately from the other numbers, to the left. How can I fix this?

Comment: The `<font>` tag [doesn't exist anymore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).

Comment: @j08691 But it does, and that's the problem. If browsers had any sense, they would invalidate code like that. But no, they keep supporting all that old stuff.

Comment: @MrLister <sigh> I know, I know...

Comment: @MrLister No it doesn't: https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete but I think your point is only that browsers still support it. That said, they can drop support for it tomorrow without notice and if it broke anyone's web page it wouldn't be anyone's fault but that web developer who decided to use `<font>`. Browsers support `<marquee>`, too, but that has never been part of any HTML specification.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No. I said if their page breaks cause they used `<font>` and browsers quit supporting it, which they will do one day.

Comment: @Rob My point is that there's a _problem_ with browsers currently supporting the old stuff. People new to HTML find old, old tutorials and they try the examples in them and they _work!_ So they won't be searching any further for good material.

Comment: @rob - Brainfart, I'm a dumbass. What would "break" is the `color` attribute, which makes perfect sense to remove. I (briefly) thought it was `style` tag, which would be weirder to not support. My point is that they could either actively discriminate against _any_ `font` tag, but you can make up any tag up and style it. But that's not the issue with `font`, so.

Comment: @MrLister I agree wholeheartedly. I understand why vendors continue to support it for some period of time after making it obsolete but I wish they would/could put a time limit on it and then drop support.

Comment: On the one hand, I can see a need for continued support for ancient webpages. You know, HTML3.2 and stuff. On the other hand, why oh why let those things keep working in HTML5? Why not have font and bgcolor only work in quirks mode!

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's a mistake to think that you can make up your own tag names. Keep to the officially defined ones! If it looks like a made up element works, that's because of the browsers _error handling_ at work. And be warned: different browsers have different error handling! See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/m1t0j7L4/2/) where the real elements are OK, but the made-up ones differ between IE and Chrome/FF.

Comment: @MrLister - You're missing the point; I _don't make up my own tag names_, but the _browser will still render them_ even if I, or anyone, did. Browsers would have to actively discriminate against a particular tag to cause any disruption.

Comment: @MrLister - span:nth-of-type(2) {color:red} selects the second span element of it's parent (there is none) - both of the statements in the fiddle are ok ... - and you are all missing the point when talking about the font tag instead of talking about the situation ...

Comment: @GalRatzkin The point of the fiddle is to prove that you shouldn't make up your own element names (which was what I thought Jared meant). If you look at the fiddle in IE11 or Edge, the made up element names behave differently from the officially defined ones.

Comment: I didn't notice that - however **you can** "make up your own elements" you just have to follow some guidelines before you do ...  [See Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830682/is-it-ok-to-use-unknown-html-tags) **Diviating from the subject even more .....**

Comment: hehehe now I noticed that you posted there ....

Comment: @darkchampionz are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would advise against using a `font` element with inline CSS as the [`font` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is now obsolete, instead use a `span` with the class red which you can then style using CSS.

Secondly wrapping all of the text in a `div` will keep them aligned.

**Example:**

```css
div.div1 {
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif">
  <div>
    One
    <br> 
    Two
    <br> 
    Three
    <br>
    <span class="red">Four</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Users that use `font` doesn't now _why_ to not use, so to add that along with your advice would be great

Comment: Thank you, I should have now edited the post to add this.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the whole statement in another tag like so :

```
    <p>One<br>Two<br>Three<br><span style="color:red">Four</span></p>
```

BTW - I dicourage style attributes in favor of a proper css file but just for demonstration's sake ...

---

This happens because when you use flex in the styling Each in-flow child of the container becomes a [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items), and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

---

Comment: This [works](https://jsfiddle.net/cyfdn0pd/), but please remove the `font` tag in favor of a `span` or some _valid_ alternative.