# What are these `dot` tags parallel to `svg` tag?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I looked at [example of `UDNZTimeline` widget](http://uonun.github.io/UDNZTimeline/demo/index.html) and saw in `Chrome` developer tools

[image]

that along with `svg` tag there is a `div` tag, containing `dot` tags. Also I saw `pole` tags somewhere in `UDNZTimeline` example. I don't see these tags in [`SVG` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element) although `Chrome` highlights visual elements on hover these tags.

The structure is like following:

```
<svg>
    <line ...>
    and other SVG tags
</svg>
<div>
    <dot ....>
    <pole ....>
    and other non-svg tags which are visualized nevertheless
</div>
```

What are these tags? How to learn about their meaning?

Comment: ["User agents must treat elements and attributes that they do not understand as semantically neutral; leaving them in the DOM (for DOM processors), and styling them according to CSS (for CSS processors), but not inferring any meaning from them."](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#extensibility-2) - it looks like site specific tags, with meaning given by the respective javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [define custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) in most browsers now:
`customElements.define(name, constructor, options);`

But after having a closer look, it seems `dot` is no defined custom element (`customElements.get('dot');` returned `undefined`).

So it seems like the devs just created elements with with name (see the source code [here](https://github.com/uonun/UDNZTimeline/blob/34325adbde130044c5be027d54449987cff1a535/src/timeline.js#L58) and [here](https://github.com/uonun/UDNZTimeline/blob/34325adbde130044c5be027d54449987cff1a535/src/timeline.js#L437)).

There seems to be no problem with browsers, since it falls back to `HTMLUnknownElement`, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830682/is-it-ok-to-use-unknown-html-tags).

And if you want to find out more about it, here is [the link to the main script](https://github.com/uonun/UDNZTimeline/blob/master/src/timeline.js).

Comment: If these are unknown elements, then how does browser know how to draw them and their location?

Comment: @Dims It's the CSS styling (`position: absolute; left: 163.44px; top: 125px;` and so on).

Edit: The unknown elements are still kept in the DOM.

Comment: Custom Elements (can be created in all Browsers, but IE) **always** have a hyphen in the node name, if you do not see one, it is never a Custom Element, if you see one it doesn't have to be a Custom Element.